# Why does android allow delete a file that being used .....?

Tags: android, delete-file, file-management

Why does android allow delete a file, although it is being used by another application?
For example: I have a mp3 file on sdcard, I use mp3 player to play it, and then I open a File Manager app and browse to that file; delete it successfully.

If on windows, a message will be displayed and we can't do that.
Why does the android operating system not?

I don't know the principle of file management on android os.
Does anyone have document about it? Help me please!

Answer (score 1):

Going with the information from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10211) (similar query to yours), linux *file deletion* only removes the pointers to the file until the last *process* using that file is complete. At this point the *contents* of the file are freed.

What this means is that the following *should not* work:

- Play an MP3 file from the SDcard.
- Open up file manager app and delete said MP3 file.
- After MP3 file finishes, attempt to play it again.